# Room Database Query - Delete User

Tags: java, android-room

I have built an app that acts as a user and inventory database using the Room persistence library. Currently I am able to make queries to view/output users to a recycler view, but I need to be able to delete a user using their **name** as the query object. Currently I have the following.

Remove User Class

```
                String usrNam = edtTxtUsrNam2.getText().toString();

                // Get all users from database + log
                List<Users> users = LoginMenu.mainDatabase.dao().getUsers();
                Log.d(LoginMenu.TAG, "Searching for " + usrNam);
                boolean userFound = false;

                // Check for User from text entry
                for (Users usr : users) {
                    // User is successfully found
                    if (usr.getName().equals(usrNam)) {
                        userFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }if (!userFound) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User not found", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(LoginMenu.TAG, " User " + usrNam + " Not found");
                    edtTxtUsrNam2.getText().clear();

                } else {
                    // Build Messagebox Confirmation
                    builder.setTitle("User " + usrNam + " found!");
                    builder.setMessage("Confirm user deletion?");

                    // Selecting yes in Alert
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialogInterface, i) -> {

                        // Delete User from database

                        Users activeUser = new Users();
                        activeUser.setName(usrNam);
                        LoginMenu.mainDatabase.dao().delUser(activeUser);
                        
                        // Toast message + Log
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User " + usrNam +
                                " successfully deleted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
                        Log.d(LoginMenu.TAG,"User " + usrNam + " Successfully deleted");
                        
                        edtTxtUsrNam2.getText().clear();
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    });
                    // Selecting no in Alert
                    builder.setNegativeButton("No", (dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.dismiss());
                    // Create Alert Dialog
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
```

DAO

```
@androidx.room.Dao
public interface Dao {

    // Add Users to Database
    @Insert
    void AddUsers(Users usr);

    // Request all users from DB
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Users")
    List<Users> getUsers();

    // Delete user from DB
    @Delete
    void delUser (Users usr);
```

User Class

```
@Entity(tableName = "Users")
public class Users {

    // Set User Entries for Database
    @ColumnInfo (name = "ID")
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "EmployeeId")
    private String  employeeId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Password")
    private String password;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "DateOfBirth")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ContactNumber")
    private String contactNumber;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Address")
    private String address;
```

It detects the user no problem at all but does not delete the User object, I'm quite new to this and would appreciate any assistance as I am sure its something simple.

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger? What does `void delUser (Users usr)` do exactly, i.e. which query does it use? It seems when you call that method the user you pass only has a name, is that the required parameter for the query?

Comment: I did not, I have just done that now. After stepping through the code I can see the void delUser (Users usr) is deleting the user I have just created which is the name only. I need to delete the entire user object found from the @Query but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Normally a DAO uses a query to delete a record it identifies by some id. That id would be the only thing needed to be passed to a delete method, e.g. `deleteUser(userId)`. The question is: is the user name used as the user's id, i.e. does it uniquely identify the user? If so, your query should reflect that.

Comment: The username is being used as the unique identifier at least in this project. Thank you Thomas, that makes complete sense now! I have managed to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are creating new user and it only has the "name" value.

```
    Users activeUser = new Users();
    activeUser.setName(usrNam); // This user is not equal what's in db.
    LoginMenu.mainDatabase.dao().delUser(activeUser);
```

Instead when you loop the users in your db if you found the user, fetch it from there like this:

```
      Users activeUser = new Users();
      for (Users usr : users) {
           // User is successfully found
           if (usr.getName().equals(usrNam)) {
               userFound = true;
               activeUser = usr; // now we got the exact item on db
               break;
           }
      }
```

Now your function will delete the correct user.

```
      //Users activeUser = new Users();
      //activeUser.setName(usrNam); //you don't need them anymore.
      LoginMenu.mainDatabase.dao().delUser(activeUser);
```

Comment: Thank you Mert! - I have tested your method as well and it works as intended :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Dao query to:

```
// Delete user from DB
    @Query("DELETE FROM Users WHERE name =:userId")
    abstract void deleteByUserId(String userId);
```

And the query itself under RemoveUsers class

```
// Delete User from database
LoginMenu.mainDatabase.dao().deleteByUserId(usrNam);
```

Query now works as intended